# Reading .txt file using pandas and slicing it based on some range in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple .txt files that are full of rubbish data and only need a portion of it based on some range that changes between files. I'm still learning Python and not very experienced.

I am using VS code 1.50 and Python 3.8.1

Sample of my data: https://pastebin.com/kZm1spnz

My first issue is with reading the .txt file, here is what I did at first:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Reading my data
Data = pd.read_csv('Data_01.txt')
```

I don't understand why it gives an error even though the python script is in the same folder as the .txt file.

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-436477220532> in <module>
      3 
      4 #Reading my data
----> 5 Data = pd.read_csv("Data_01.txt", sep="\t", names=["Depth", "Porosity"])

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    934             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    935 
--> 936         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    937 
    938     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1166     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1167         if engine == "c":
-> 1168             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1169         else:
   1170             if engine == "python":

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1997 
-> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2000 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data_01.txt'
```

I fixed it by using the full path of my data file but I don't understand the need for the full path, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Reading my data
Data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\SDP\Data_01.txt", sep="\t", names=["Depth", "Porosity"])
```

Now when slicing my data, I did not want to use Indices, i.e., "iloc" & "loc", to keep my code readable and easy to manipulate and to reapply for the other files, maybe use a for loop to sweep through them all in one run. So I tested first by using the following:

```
Data_result_1 = Data[Data['Depth'] >= 7711]
```

This works, however, I wish to use an additional condition in the same line where it stops at Depth = 7786, i.e., my range. But it does not work, here is the code I wrote that failed:

```
Data_result_1 = Data[Data['Depth'] >= 7711 and Data['Depth'] <= 7786]
```

Is there a way to use the nested conditions without creating a new line of code, I was able to reach my desired result by it feels unnecessary and, to be frank, ugly. here is what works:

```
Data_result_1 = Data[Data['Depth'] >= 7711 ] 
Data_result_1 = Data_result_1[Data_result_1['Depth'] <= 7786]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use & instead of and:

```
Data_result_1 = Data[ (Data['Depth'] >= 7711) & (Data['Depth'] <= 7786)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted for the second part, thanks!

Comment: can you send me the text file so that I can help you for the first part as well?

Comment: Yes please:
Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ucezkgezz0tj8k/Data_01.txt?dl=0
or: https://pastebin.com/kZm1spnz

Comment: I checked it with VS code and pandas 3.8.5 it worked fine. If the file is in the same folder it's weird that you have problem with it.https://www.dropbox.com/s/q80j6hr91j0sm0a/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: Can you check if you have the same problem in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, the same error is happening in Jupyter. I ran "pd.show_version()" and showed that my pandas version is: 1.1.2. I upgraded just in case and showed the same error even when using different python versions. so weird.

Comment: I don't think this problem refers to your python and pandas. Maybe the root of the problem is the file system.